ScrollView becomes temporarily unresponsive
I am having an issue where my content contained in a scroll view is unable to be scrolled at random intervals. It also specifically has an issue where if it is scrolled and it comes to a rest it is not able to be scrolled for anywhere from 3 to 10 seconds.
Currently it is formatted as follows:
<SafeAreaView>
  <KeyboardAvoidingView
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
    keyboardVerticalOffset={50}
  >
    <ScrollView
      scrollContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}
      contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: "center" }}
    >
      {/* Content */}
    </ScrollView>
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
</SafeAreaView>

What I am attempting to do is vertically center the content on the page, while allowing it to be pushed upward when necessary such as when the content expands or when the keyboard is pulled up.

Imagine your content is rather large and you are experiencing a performance penalty. More than that is difficult to say without context (size of the content, available capacity of your device, other applications running simultaneously, possibly some other performance-heavy part of your app running simultaneously). Besides something blocking the main thread (above) unresponsiveness may be also caused by some other (potentially not visible) element covering the target of your desired action. I would also try to check superfluous re-renders.
